# Kotlin: pass class type used in filterIsInstance in a function

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have written a function in kotlin

```
private fun mapBasketToTeam(basketIter: GenericBasket) {
        val fruitBasket = basketIter.basketTypeMap.getOrDefault(BasketType.FRUIT, listOf())
                .filterIsInstance<FruitBasket>()
        val groceryBasket = basketIter.basketTypeMap.getOrDefault(BasketType.GROCERY, listOf())
                .filterIsInstance<GroceryBasket>()
}
```

Now I want to simplify it by creating a new function which takes type of class as `GroceryBasket` or `FruitBasket` and returns me `List<GroceryBasket>` or `List<FruitBasket>` respectively. So that there will be no duplication of same code in two lines.

Is there any way to pass the class type to the function which can be then passed to `filterIsInstance`?

Comment: Are these already sorted by type? I see you are pulling out a list by `BasketType`. Will the list associated with `BasketType.FRUIT` already contain exclusively `FruitBasket` items, for example?

Comment: Yes. the map associates enum to List<Basket>. For enum FRUIT, the value in map corresponding to key FRUIT will be a List<Basket>, all entries are of type FruitBasket.

Comment: So instead of using filterByInstance, if there is any other way to convert parent class list to child class list, it can be used directly.

Comment: Only by unsafe casting. But if you control the functions for adding and retrieving items, you can ensure the safety yourself. I think the BasketType enum is adding complexity, though. I added an answer for how to do it without the enum.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the `BasketType` enum for anything besides sorting these items, you could eliminate the enum and change the key type of your map in GenericBasket to KClass. Then you could add a function to your GenericBasket like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> getBasketsOfType(): List<T> = 
    basketTypeMap[T::class].orEmpty().filterIsInstance<T>()
```

And then use it like this:

```
private fun mapBasketToTeam(basketIter: GenericBasket) {
        val fruitBasket = basketIter.getBasketsOfType<FruitBasket>()
        val groceryBasket = basketIter.getBasketsOfType<GroceryBasket>() 
}
```

If there's some reason you need to keep your enum, I don't see how you can do this without unsafe casting.